# Configure apache to 'overide' default file location

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect

The question is :
Can I somehow configure Apache to use alternative directory, or rather to search alternative directory first, and if file is found then to use that one, rather than the original.

Say I have a configuration like this :

```
/var/www/mysite/images/somefile.jpg
```

as well as:

```
/var/www/custom_theme/images/somefile.jpg
```

Now, the file in second location may or may not be present. If its present I would like that one to be used instead of the one in `mysite`. Is that possible to do with Apache virtual host configuration (`custom_theme` folder will vary depending on the domain used to access the site)?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming **/var/www/** is your **DocumentRoot**, so both the: **mysite** and the: **custom_theme** directories are directly and publicly accessible, then you could achieve what you want via a re-write rule e.g.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}                  ^/mysite/images/([^/]+\.jpg)$              
RewriteCond /var/www/custom_theme/images/%1 -f
RewriteRule .*                              /custom_theme/images/%1 [L]
```